# Facing Issue for Installing Rabit MQ

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, unix, ubuntu-10.04

Whem I am using the below command

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

I am getting the below missing package dependency

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
rabbitmq-server is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
erlang-nox : Depends: erlang-base but it is not going to be installed or
                   erlang-base-hipe but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-asn1 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-corba but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-crypto but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-diameter but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-docbuilder but it is not installable
          Depends: erlang-edoc but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-erl-docgen but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-eunit but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-ic but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-inets but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-inviso but it is not installable
          Depends: erlang-mnesia but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-odbc but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-os-mon but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-parsetools but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-percept but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-public-key but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-runtime-tools but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-snmp but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-ssh but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-ssl but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-syntax-tools but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-tools but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-webtool but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-xmerl but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I am unable to understand how to install all these packages and then install Rabit-MQ

I have also tried downloading the

rabbitmq-server_3.5.6-1_all.deb

and then use the command

```
 sudo dpkg -i rabbitmq-server_3.5.6-1_all.deb
```

But I am getting output as

```
 (Reading database ... 320808 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to unpack rabbitmq-server_3.5.6-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking rabbitmq-server (3.5.6-1) over (3.5.6-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rabbitmq-server:
 rabbitmq-server depends on erlang-nox (>= 1:13.b.3) | esl-erlang; however:
  Package erlang-nox is not configured yet.
  Package esl-erlang is not installed.

 dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-2) ...
 Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 rabbitmq-server
```

What Am I doing Wronge.

Please advice!!

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting all those unmet dependency errors because you are trying to install software on a version of Ubuntu that has reached end of life and therefore it's no longer supported. The sensible thing to do is to backup your data and do a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04, which is also a Long Term Support release like Ubuntu 10.04.

Alternatively you could do a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10. Ubuntu 15.10, which will be released in a few days on October 22, has almost the same version of rabbitmq-server that you are trying to install in its official repositories, so you certainly won't get any errors if you install rabbitmq-server 3.5.4-1 from the Ubuntu Software Center in Ubuntu 15.10.

Instead of doing a fresh install, you could also try to upgrade Ubuntu 10.04 to Ubuntu 14.04 by following the instructions in [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading), however this is liable to result in a misconfigured system.

Answer (score 1):

This Solution worked for me

add this line:

```
deb http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/debian precise contrib
```

to:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

then in terminal run below commands:

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install erlang-nox    
sudo apt-get install socat    
sudo wget http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v3.6.9/rabbitmq-server_3.6.9-1_all.deb    
sudo dpkg -i rabbitmq-server_3.6.9-1_all.deb
```